# Update position of custom QGraphicsItem on connected item change

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt, qgraphicsitem

I have two subclassed QGraphicsRectItems that are supposed to be connected with a line that adjusts based on the position of the textboxes.

In the [diagramscene example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-diagramscene-example.html) of the Qt docus the `itemChanged` method of a subclassed `QGraphicsPolygonItem` calls a `updatePosition` method of the connected arrow which calls `setLine` to update the arrow's position. In my case I cannot call `setLine` as I am subclassing `QGraphicsItem` instead of `QGraphicsLineItem`.

How should I implement `updatePosition` method in the `Arrow` class below to update the position of my QGraphicsItem? The following is a runnable example that shows what happens currently when the textboxes are clicked and moved.

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *


class Arrow(QGraphicsItem):

    def __init__(self, startItem, endItem, parent=None, scene=None):
        super().__init__(parent, scene)

        self.startItem = startItem
        self.endItem = endItem

    def boundingRect(self):
        p1 = self.startItem.pos() + self.startItem.rect().center()
        p3 = self.endItem.pos() + self.endItem.rect().center()
        bounds = p3 - p1
        size = QSizeF(abs(bounds.x()), abs(bounds.y()))
        return QRectF(p1, size)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):

        p1 = self.startItem.pos() + self.startItem.rect().center()
        p3 = self.endItem.pos() + self.endItem.rect().center()

        pen = QPen()
        pen.setWidth(1)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        if self.isSelected():
            pen.setStyle(Qt.DashLine)
        else:
            pen.setStyle(Qt.SolidLine)

        pen.setColor(Qt.black)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawLine(QLineF(p1, p3))
        painter.setBrush(Qt.NoBrush)

    def updatePosition(self):
        #Not sure what to do here...


class TextBox(QGraphicsRectItem):

    def __init__(self, text, position, rect=QRectF(0, 0, 200, 100),
                 parent=None, scene=None):
        super().__init__(rect, parent, scene)

        self.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable |
                      QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable |
                      QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)

        self.text = QGraphicsTextItem(text, self)  

        self.setPos(position)

        self.arrows = []

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        painter.setPen(Qt.black)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setBrush(Qt.white)
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())

    def addArrow(self, arrow):
        self.arrows.append(arrow)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionChange:
            for arrow in self.arrows:
                arrow.updatePosition()

        return value


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QGraphicsView()
    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 500, 1000)
    view.setScene(scene)

    textbox1 = TextBox("item 1", QPointF(50, 50), scene=scene)
    textbox1.setZValue(1)
    textbox2 = TextBox("item 2", QPointF(100, 500), scene=scene)
    textbox2.setZValue(1)

    arrow = Arrow(textbox1, textbox2, scene=scene)
    arrow.setZValue(0)

    textbox1.addArrow(arrow)
    textbox2.addArrow(arrow)

    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Easiest way omho is to use `QGraphicsItemGroup` or the parent-child relation. You don't need to do anything fancy after that in order to make things move together since these two ways of doing it take care of all that.

Comment: I could see your suggestion working for the case where all of the items move at the same time but not one of the other. Is that the case?

Comment: I don't think so. So basically you want to "stretch" the connection but only move the node that you've selected? If so take a look [here](http://www.walletfox.com/course/qgraphicsitemruntimedrawing.php). It shows drawing while moving the mouse which is basically what you want to do - whenever you move one of the nodes, you need to recreate the connection and update it until the moved node is left alone in which case you simply put the last state of the moved connection to be the final one.

Comment: For the `TextBox` class I've now implemented the mouse press/release events to toggle an updating mode and mouseMoveEvent which calls `arrow.update()` to trigger a paint event. I can see that the paint event is being triggered, but I still get the same behaviour as in the gif for some reason.

Comment: Usually when you get crappy drawing it's because of an incorrect bounding box. If you try to draw outside the bounding box you get that kind of glitch behaviour seen in the GIF.

Comment: The bounding box seems okay initially: `QRectF(150.0, 100.0, 50.0, 450.0)` with points p1: `QPointF(150.0, 100.0)` and p3: `QPointF(200.0, 550.0)` just on the edges of the box. I also added a padding to the box of 10 pixels and same thing. So it seems like the bounding box must not be updating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The position of the item doesn't actually matter - it can remain at 0,0 - providing the bounding box is correct (which it will be according to your Arrow::boundingBox implementation). Hence, I think if you simply trigger a bounding box change, and a redraw in updatePosition, everything will work as you want.

Of course, if you care about the position of the arrow being at the head or tail of the line, you can move it in updatePosition, and adjust the bounding box / paint coordinates accordingly - but that's entirely up to you if that makes sense or not.

Comment: How would I trigger a bounding box change and redraw? I've tried using `self.prepareGeometryChange()` and `self.update()` to do this in `updatePosition` but am still getting the same behaviour.

Comment: It work perfectly now! In addition to what I mentioned above I had to set the `ItemSendsGeometryChanges` flag in the `TextBox` init and change `QSizeF(abs(bounds.x()), abs(bounds.y())` to `QSizeF(bounds.x(), bounds.y())` in the `boundingRect` method of `Arrow`